# Increase electret microphone bias voltage

Tags: microphone, bias, electret

I've got a Zalman zm-mic1 microphone, that was working just fine on my laptop. I bought a new rig a couple of months ago and the microphone is really quiet, digital amplification introduces an enormous amount of noise while my voice is still barely audible. Tried everything on the software side, nothing helped.

I measured the bias voltage and got 2.25 V, while i had 3.85 V on the laptop. So I checked the the audio codec's datasheet (ALC887) and it says "Software selectable 2.5V/3.75V VREFOUT to be analog microphone bias". Well this software selection is nowhere to be found, neither in the official driver, nor in the BIOS and google doesn't help either.

So the question would be, is there any way of increasing the bias voltage externally, that doesn't include me buying another sound card/microphone. Or should I just build a preamp with the LM386. You can see the wiring of the microphone jack on the following picture (taken from the datasheet).

[image: ALC887 microphone connection circuit]

PS: Since it's a new PC, and my knowledge on the field is obviously lacking, I don't want to get funky with the motherboard.

Comment: Are you sure you are not just getting what you should from a 5 bucks microphone? Maybe instead of fiddling around invest the time and effort into buyinig a better microphone that comes with its own power...

Comment: Yea... you're probably right, but i like fixing stuff instead of throwing them out, if there is an easy way.

Comment: for a 5 bucks microphone imho there is not much to "fix". Even if you manage to get some better biasing and preamp done it will most likely be much more (especially if you consider your time being money) than a cheap boya lav or so, which isn't great either but very likely better than that thing.

Comment: well, considering how much trouble it caused me because they couldn't hear me on the other end of the line and also investigating you definitely right. No science for me i guess.

Comment: get a better microphone and build a preamp for that. Much more satisfying.